# Meteor adds _proto_ to array

Tags: javascript, arrays, meteor

I'm having an issue with arrays in Meteor where Meteor is adding a *proto* field to the array objects despite the fact I only add the object.
I've tested this outside of Meteor and my array only has the fields I pass it.

Normal (non-Meteor) code:

```
function coisa() {
    var a = [];

    b = [];

    function test() {
        c = [];
        a.push(1, 2, 3);
        b.push(4, 5, 6);
        c.push(7, 8, 9);
    }

    function loggerA() {
        return a;
    }

    function loggerB() {
        return b;
    }

    function loggerC() {
        return c;
    }

    test();

    console.log(loggerA());
    console.log(loggerB());
    console.log(loggerC());
}
coisa();
```

Meteor code:

```
if (Meteor.isClient) {
    Template.hello.rendered = function () {
        var a = [];

        b = [];

        function test() {
            c = [];
            a.push(1, 2, 3);
            b.push(4, 5, 6);
            c.push(7, 8, 9);
        }

        function logger() {
            console.log(a);
            console.log(b);
            console.log(c);
        }
/*        function loggerA() {
            return a;
        }

        function loggerB() {
            return b;
        }

        function loggerC() {
            return c;
        }

        */

        test();
        logger();

//        console.log(loggerA());
//        console.log(loggerB());
//        console.log(loggerC());
    }
}

if (Meteor.isServer) {
    Meteor.startup(function () {
        // code to run on server at startup
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with this, its a part of the ECMA 6 javascript spec as it was built, as is found in modern web browsers. Any javascript object has a `__proto__` object that allows you to place properties that can be inherited when you alter the array.

You can read more about it here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/proto

This shouldn't impact your app in any way, its usually ignored/not visible when you loop through your objects, unless you explicitly call it. The `__` is added to the start of it so its minimally intrusive.

Comment: But why does it only show with Meteor and not regular code?

Comment: @mesosteros It would be there as long as its javascript, so long as you view it under a modern web browser. Meteor doesn't add it, the ES6 pre-final javascript spec adds it. It's only visible under a debugger. If you call it even outside a debugger using `xxx.__proto__` you will be able to see its properties.

Comment: @mesosteros Please look at javascript questions that ask the same thing such as this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8665446/where-does-proto-get-added-to-array

Comment: @mesosteros I'm not seeing any difference between Meteor and the javascript code you've given, are you using different ways to view them?

Comment: Darn I had forgotten my code and what I actually wanted to ask... which is why does _proto_ get added to my array regardless of being Meteor or not. Your answer cleared that. Thank you.